# Displaying data from http flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

hi i'm trying to display the data from http for my project, so far i already connected to the backend and get the response body using http authentication

the response.body from json :

```
{
    "count": 302
}
```

i wanted to display the "302" to my display, using future and future builder

the model

```
  final String Count;

  const Post({required this.Count});

  static Post fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> post) => Post(Count: post['count']);
}
```

trying to map the response body using Map<string,dynamic>

```
    final completer = Completer<List<Post>>();
response.then((value) {
      _handleResponse(value);
      List<Post> posts = [
        Post.fromJson(jsonDecode(value.body) as Map<String, dynamic>)
      ];

      completer.complete(posts);
    });
```

the future builder :

```
class PostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  PostPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PostPage> createState() => _PostPageState();
}

class _PostPageState extends State<PostPage> {
  final authe count = authe();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // getCount();
    return
        // Text(c);
        FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
      future: count.makeGetRequest(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final posts = snapshot.data;
          return Text("posts");
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

but when i put it to my main dart all i got is this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMjnP.png

did my future builder didn't get my data from my authentication file?

Comment: Did you debug your code? is there any error while fromJson or api call?

Comment: One thing that's wrong is that you literally make the text display "posts". You probably want it to be `Text(posts.first.Count)`, but that doesn't seem to be the main issue that you have now. What does `count.makeGetRequest()` look like? You have not included that part

Comment: I also recommend that you follow the coding convention to have class names with a capital letter and variables with a small. You have it mixed now. For example `authe` and `Count` instead of `Authe` and `count`

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a dynamic list and assign your response.body to it. It lead to this :

`var mylist =[]; myList= jsonDecode(response.body); print(mylist[count]) ;`